# Disabling the asp.net link button n radios using Jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

How to disable the asp.net Link buttons and  asp.net radio buttons.
I have used

to enable 
  $("#sLbtnFirst").attr("disabled", "");
to disable
 $("#sLbtnFirst").attr("disabled", "disabled");

but i'm able to click the buttons they are just greying

Comment: disabled is an HTML attribute which is not enforced by ASP.NET. You're looking for the Enabled property of the ListButton control. Also, I suggest using `$("#sLbtnFirst").removeAttr("disabled")` instead of setting the value to nothing in situations where you need to "unset" an HTML attribute.

Comment: You have to make sure that the click event is realy on the html element with the id sLbtnFirst. And I would rather use css classes to change the attributes (.addClass and .removeClass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET radio buttons, the attribute that specifies whether they're clickable is called "enabled", not "disabled".

But, at client-side they are rendered as html input tags which do contain the attribute "disabled" so to disable them you would want to use:

```
$("#sRbtnFirst").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

To enable:

```
$("#sRbtnFirst").removeAttr("disabled");
```

EDIT: I've tried your jQuery myself in a .NET app and it seems to grey out the radio buttons fine (and prevent clicking).  The LinkButton's a different story though.

You'll also need to remove the "href" attribute to prevent it from performing an action on click.  So:

```
$("#sLbtnFirst").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#sLbtnFirst").removeAttr("href");
```

That should disable the LinkButton.

Also, remember that your IDs will change when they are rendered in the form so they won't be what they are when you view your aspx page in Visual Studio.  .NET will change them into something like:

```
#ct100_sLbtnFirst
```

Answer (score 0):

Link buttons render as anchor tags (`<a href=`) and the `disabled` attribute is not defined for [this tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2). As far as radio buttons are concerned you could apply the `disabled` attribute to them, they will grey out and their value **won't** be sent when you post the form.

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable linkbutton, try this:

```
//disabling
document.getElementById('sLbtnFirst').onclick = function() {return false;}
//enabling
document.getElementById('sLbtnFirst').onclick = function() {return true;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$("#sRbtnFirst").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: I fixed the typo, you can delete your answer now. I reworded it so it actually answers the question and is not a comment. Please read how to format code on StackOverflow.